# Convert alpha channel to new image

Tags: gimp

I would like to convert the alpha channel into a new image:

[image]

I didn't find any way to do that.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
I selected the alpha channel, copied it, then "Paste as new image".